# How to run CakePHP on nginx of Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: nginx, mariadb, cakephp-3.0

I created CakePHP project on Window 7 and I sent that project under folder(/usr/share/nginx/html/ ) of Ubuntu 14.04 Server.

I installed php, nginx in Ubuntu Server.
How to run CakePHP project

Comment: What output do you get when accessing your server in a browser?

Comment: When I access ubuntu server IP address, nginx server page show in a browser

Comment: Okay, so what do you see if you go to http://[ip]/[app_name]? I assume your project is stored under `/usr/share/nginx/html/[app_name]`

Comment: http://[ip]/[app_name] display 403 Forbidden

Comment: Maybe a permissions issue. Can the webserver user (www-data probably) read the directory? Also, don't think this question belongs here at all.

Comment: Is it necessary to prompt command (bin/cake server) because of  I'm using nginx server?

Comment: No, that's not necessary. Nginx is a webserver right? Sorry you don't need CakePHPs little test server. But like I asked, are permissions set correctly?

Comment: Thank Roberto,
I think It was wrong the root path( root /usr/share/nginx/html/app_name/webroot); Now It was OK

Answer (score 0):

You don't actively 'run' a CakePHP project. You put the files somewhere where they are accessible by the webserver, who than executes your code for a HTTP request.

In your case you shouldn't have to do much more. Assuming that `/usr/share/nginx/html/` is the default of your server, you can simply go to your servers IP address and that should be it.